# Magento 2 debug router

Tags: magento2, debug, routes

Is there some functionality to view all routes same like **Symfony(router:debug)** which shows us all the available routes(URL) in the current application.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: No**

Below you can find explanation how routes in Magento 2 are generated:

You can get that information by reading classes inside `Controller` directories and looking inside routes.xml files.

This is example how routes.xml can look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="module_router" frontName="myrouter">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Example Controller class:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Custom;

class Show extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
    ) {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

The result pattern is like that:
`myrouter/custom/show`

`myrouter` comes from frontName.

`custom` comes from your namespace part after Controller.

`show` comes from your class name

If you name your class `Index`, both routes `myrouter/custom/index` and `myrouter/custom` will point to your new action class.
Same goes for namespace part after `Controller`, so all three routes will work: `myrouter/index/index` and `myrouter/index` and `myrouter`.

There are also URL rewrites and custom routers which both can mask your full action url with some features. URL rewrites for example are used for prduct urls. So you can view your product with url like `example.com/my-product-url-key` and `example.com/catalog/product/view/id/1`.

Routes can be usefull if you wan't to achieve more complex routing. For example  `example.com/manufacturer/some-brand` can point to your custom action, where you can load and show information about brand loaded by code `some-brand`.